# How to update Struts2 s:select with values from other s:selects in jsp

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, struts2, onchange

- I'm working on a Java + JSP + Struts2 application. In one of the
  steps I need to get some inputs from the user, so I show a list of
  objects and I ask the user to choose among certain values I propose
  to him/her.

  - Every object has up to 6 different selects where the user must choose
    one of the proposed.
  - There could be from 1 to n different objects shown.
  - All this is perfectly working.

Now, I want to check that the user is NOT choosing the same option in different object's select. I mean, the option choosen in the *select number 1* should be unique for all possible *selects number 1*. The option chooseen in the *select number 2* should be unique for all possible *selects number 2* ... and so on till select number 6.

I don't know if I should focuss this through validateable from struts2, or from AJAX / JQUERY.

Here is some code (HTML+JSP+STRUTS2):

```
<s:iterator value="listaProfesASustituir" var="listaSustitucionesAInsertar" status="listaProfesASustituirStatus">
  <s:select list="profesPrimera" name="profeSustitutoPrimera" />
  <s:select list="profesPrimera" name="profeSustitutoSegunda" />
  <s:select list="profesPrimera" name="profeSustitutoTercera" />
  <s:select list="profesPrimera" name="profeSustitutoCuarta" />
  <s:select list="profesPrimera" name="profeSustitutoQuinta" />
  <s:select list="profesPrimera" name="profeSustitutoSexta" />
</s:iterator>
```

After that, I finnally submit the info with a form that surrounds all the code above.

I've been reading a lot over this, most people tried to solve this through onchange event, but since I need to focuss the pairs to be checked among 6 different selects ... and since I don't know how many objects will be created... I'm kind of lost.

Can you please put some light in here?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: IMO you'd be better off doing the entire thing using plain JS or jQuery, i.e., skip the S2 tags altogether. You'll need an `onChange` for each select that modifies the other selects' options so when a choice is made it's removed from all the others. You'll also need to *restore* options when they're *de*-selected, so it's likely you'd want to expose the data to JS anyway, either via Ajax or by rendering it into the JSP.

Comment: Hi @Dave Newton! And thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm a really beginner with front technologies... Sip I'm completely lost with JavaScript, Ajax, jQuery and so on. Could you please be so kind to share some point where to begin with the objetive I have? I have read about it... But nothing that can make me think I'm even in the right direction :-( I really want to do this, same if in the process I learn something about front: that would be great!!

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton do you have any idea where I can begin with this? The closer thing I get shearching is copying from one select to others ... but this solution lies on a "father" that "teaches his children" the option that should be taken ... but my need is to be "all brothers". I mean, any select must modify all of its kind. Thank you!!